# Is there a git merge strategy that copes with significant code movement?

Tags: git

In my branch, I moved 90% of the methods from one test class to another.

In main branch, someone added one method to the class I moved the code out of.

Then I went to do a downmerge; our convention is that you always merge from the main branch to your work branch before going the other way. I used:

```
git pull origin develop
```

The resulting merge created a file containing all the code that I had removed. I would have expected a 3-way merge to apply, which would have 'kept' my deletion and the other branch's addition. So I had to manually re-edit to get rid of all the classes that I'd deleted from the 'origin' class. Of course, I had to manually move the one new method; no objection there.

Is there an alternative git merge strategy which might have recognized what I meant?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's the problem? You're going to pull those changes into the main branch. Nothing will happen to your branch. Now merge your branch into the main branch.

Comment: Does the edit help? Of course something happened to my branch. git pull origin develop left me with a hammered file full of unwanted code, and I'd hope that git could do better.

Comment: You pulled from the repo onto your branch?

Comment: what do you mean `The resulting merge proposed...`? a ff occurred?

Comment: Is rebasing your branch  on top of the develop branch an option?  Git might be happier applies changes that way.

Comment: we push branches for review and are not enthusiastic history rewriters; so, I could use rebase but I'd rather not.

Comment: Worth a shot to see if a rebase applies cleanly at least, even if you don't keep the changes.

Comment: Re-writing history is only tabu in the context of repos that are shared.  I've seen only two arguments against rebase for un-published work: you lose the history of what used to be there (in the thousands of times I've rebased this has been an issue 3 or 4 times; granted that's a very small sample); and you can end up resolving the same merge conflict multiple times if you have multiple commits changing the same piece of code.

Comment: @bmargulies Actually `git pull --rebase` is exactly doing *what you want*. I don't get why you would *rather use it*. The artifical tool you have in mind would need to do the same. I think it is funny that so many (even good developers and/ot engineers) fear the usage of `git rebase`. Of course you should never use it on a public shared branch, but in all other cases it is so much powerful!!! A git without the rebase command would like an alcoholic-free beer for me. :)

Comment: I've said *never use it on a public shared branch*. This is not fully correct. Correct would be: Never rebase that part of the history which has been shared to public. Regardless of the branch you are working on. But `git pull --rebase` is ok in this case!

Comment: If you don't want to rebase, IMO your best bet is: do the merge, anything that conflicts: `git checkout ...` your version, then manually edit in their changes.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to:

```
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

This puts your local commits on top of the remote commits.

Comment: +1, but in my experience once someone gets to the point where they're dealing with merge conflicts, switching to a rebase workflow is painful.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I'm used to the pull request based workflow. Rebasing - execpt of the upstream master branch ;) - is not painful when doing so. That's why I prefer the pull request based workflow. However `git pull --rebase` won't harm even in this case.

Comment: I've seen it be an issue with people who are still fairly new to git.  They've done many pull requests to stay up to date, so rebasing causes them heartache when they have to re-resolve their merge conflicts.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg [rerere](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) to the rescue.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I would threaten new users with the death penality if the they should use the plain `git rebase` command! :) But a `git pull --rebase` shouldn't harm (as long as they are supposed to know the codebase but just not familiar with git). Correct me if I'm too naive.

Comment: I agree -- with new developers.  Once they're familiar enough with git, it is an incredibly useful tool and only a problem for everyone else if they alter history before their own commits.

Comment: You can prevent anyone from pushing commits that alter history (on origin) through the main repo's config.  I recently changed ours so reflog is enabled on the bare repo, and you can't alter history with `git push` -- you have to do it with `git update-ref` directly.